# How do I select the anchor of a link wth pure javascript

Tags: javascript

So if I have a DOM like this :

```
<div id="foo">
<ul><li><a href="#"></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

I understand to grab the div I would do

```
   document.getElementById("foo");
```

but how could I grab the a ?  I am trying to add a class to the a href.

ME = spoiled by jQuery

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: `document.links` is also available as you've attached a `href` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing that you can select by there is the tag name (`a`).  You can use the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByTagName) method for this:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
el.className = 'foo';
```

Note that `[0]` selects the *first* element found by `getElementsByTagName`.  Obviously this can return multiple elements.

If you want to search just within `#foo`, you could do this:

```
var foo = document.getElementById('foo'),
    el = foo.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
```

This shows that you can use `getElementsByTagName` to search within the context of another element.

---

One final method -- that isn't supported in all browsers (i.e. Firefox 3 or before, IE 7 or before) -- is [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll), which allows you to use CSS selectors much as you would in jQuery.  For instance:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('#foo a')[0];
```